# Why does std::list want to call my allocator with no arguments?

Tags: c++, memory-management, std

Sorry, I can not paste the specific code.
I hope this small sample is enough:

Let's say I have an allocator like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyAllocator
{
// ... typedefs

    MyAllocObject _allocObject;

public:
    MyAllocator() {
    // _allocObject = new ..
    }

    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator& alloc) {
        _allocObject = alloc.getAllocObject();
    }

    template <class U>
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U>& alloc) {
        _allocObject = alloc.getAllocObject();
    }

    MyAllocator(const MyAllocObject& allocObject) {
        _allocObject = allocObject;
    }

    inline pointer allocate(size_type size) {
        return _allocObject->alloc(size);
    }

// other functions
};
```

And is used like this:

```
MyAllocObject object;
MyAllocator<int> myAlloc(object);
std::list<int, MyAllocator<int> > list(myAlloc);
```

I experienced, that if the default constructor is missing, the code does not compile, so I added it.
But the problem is, that I depend on that argument, because that is what I use for my custom memory allocations.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Before C++11, allocators had to behave as-if stateless, i.e. two instances of the same type, no matter how they were intialized, had to be exchangable. 

(This requirement stems from moving elements from one container to another)

C++ 11 adds requirement for stateful allocators.  Before C++11, allocators had to behave as-if stateless, i.e. two instances of the same type, no matter how they were intialized, had to be exchangable. 

C++ 11 adds requirement for stateful allocators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861046/compiler-support-for-stateful-allocators-in-stl-containers

Comment: What platform, compiler and options are you working with?

Comment: @Niall: I wanted to expand a bit before posting as answer. Done :) -- unfortunately, I couldn't find a nice intro to using stateful allocators.

Comment: @peterchen. No problem, +1 on the answer, that does pretty much sum it up. C++11 did bring a number of changes to the allocators, I can't remember what they all were, but this was one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++11, STL implementations were allowed to require allocators to behave as-if stateless.

*"behave as-if stateless"* means STL could rely on the following to work:

```
MyAllocator a1;
void * p = a1.allocate(77, 0);

MyAllocator a2;
a2.free(p);
```

(IIRC this simplifies implementation of some container operations.)

*"were allowed to require"* means STL implementation *could* support stateful allocators (like yours), but didn't have to.

---

C++ 11 requires support for stateful allocators.
I couldn't, however, find a quick introduction to that (anyone wants to add that?) [This thread might give you some leads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861046/compiler-support-for-stateful-allocators-in-stl-containers).

---

If you are bound to a particular compiler that does not support stateful allocators, you have a few not-so-shiny options:

- include a reference to your state as template argument of the allocator
- in your allocation, include a back-link to the allocator in question (usually destroys the purpose of a custom allocator for small data)